# CL8800: how RC bridge regulate the tap current?

Tags: voltage-regulator, switch-mode-power-supply

As in CL8800 datasheet, page 8, the document refers to simplified block diagram (Figure 3-6)

How do I calculate the value or R_SET for controlling the amount of current in each tap?

What is the relation between R_SET and I_TAP if V_TAP is given?

Thanks in advance!

http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20005357A.pdf

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the datasheet provides only this bit of help, in the "Overview" subsection of the "Design Information" section:

> Manually selecting values will provide light, but the chosen values
>   may be far from optimal in regards to efficiency, LED utilization, and
>   line regulation. Contact your nearest Microchip Field Applications
>   Engineer for design assistance.

It doesn't look like this device is intended for the casual hobbyist.